# How onClick image with gridLayout to different Activity

Tags: android, fragment

This is my image:

[image: This my image]

If I need to try anything please advice me.

My code fragment:

```
public class ShopFragment extends Fragment {

private  int imgShop[] = {R.drawable.thumbnail_01,
        R.drawable.thumbnail_02,
        R.drawable.thumbnail_03,
        R.drawable.thumbnail_04,
        R.drawable.thumbnail_05,
        R.drawable.thumbnail_06};
ViewPager pager;
SearchView searchView;

private int img[] = {R.drawable.scroll_view, R.drawable.scroll_view, R.drawable.scroll_view, R.drawable.scroll_view};


public ShopFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

private ArrayList<Shop> prepareShop() {

    ArrayList<Shop> shop = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < imgShop.length; i++) {
        Shop shops = new Shop();
        shops.setShop_img(imgShop[i]);
        shop.add(shops);
    }
    return shop;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shop, container, false);




    pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.img_pager);
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getContext(), img);
    pager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);


    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.mRecyclerShop);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutmanager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);


    ArrayList<Shop> shops = prepareShop();
    ShopRecycleAdaptor adaptor = new ShopRecycleAdaptor(getContext(), shops);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptor);

    return view;
}
```

my adapter

```
public class ShopRecycleAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShopRecycleAdaptor.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<Shop> shop;
private Context context;
private int[] imgShop;



public ShopRecycleAdaptor(Context context, ArrayList<Shop> shop) {
    this.shop = shop;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ShopRecycleAdaptor.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model_shop, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ShopRecycleAdaptor.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(shop.get(position)
            .getShop_img())
            .into(holder.imgShop);
    holder.imgShop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ShopType.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra("shop", shop);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return shop.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView imgShop;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {

        super(view);

        imgShop = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_shop);
    }

}
```

and this my error

> 05-13 11:45:54.091 8712-8712/com.example.androiddev.army31 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                Process: com.example.androiddev.army31, PID: 8712
>                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.example.androiddev.army31.Shop@778fcae
>                                                                                    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1476)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:811)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1423)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:723)
>                                                                                    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1412)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1133)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:763)
>                                                                                    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:8788)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3071)
>                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1539)
>                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4391)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
>                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4335)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
>                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4697)
>                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4665)
>                                                                                    at com.example.androiddev.army31.ShopRecycleAdaptor$1.onClick(ShopRecycleAdaptor.java:57)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5646)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22458)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6524)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `Shop` class Parcelable? To put any custom class into a Bundle the class must implement the Parcelable interface. See here.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Your stack trace error suggests that the info being added is not in fact Parcelable compliant, so it's not the `onClick` error that's causing the issue its the

```
intent.putExtra("shop", shop);
```

line if I am reading this correctly.

Comment: @C.Junior thanks, if it worked please do accept this as the answer!